# Python downloading data from list of url

Tags: python, database, pandas, beautifulsoup, download

I have got this code handed down. Now, I have to reference this code to a list:

```
List_Of_Teams = [https://www.soccerbase.com/teams/team.sd?team_id=1724&comp_id=1&teamTabs=results, https://www.soccerbase.com/teams/team.sd?team_id=17&comp_id=19&teamTabs=results, ....]
Team_Names = [Man Utd, Atalanta, .....]
```

Such that the output remains the same i.e. Teams data getting downloaded in their respective csv files.
How can I go along with it?

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://www.soccerbase.com/teams/home.sd'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
teams = soup.find('div', {'class': 'headlineBlock'}, text='Team').next_sibling.find_all('li')

teams_dict = {}
for team in teams:
    link = 'https://www.soccerbase.com' + team.find('a')['href']
    team = team.text

    teams_dict[team] = link

for k, v in teams_dict.items():
    print('Acquiring %s data...' % k)

    headers = ['Competition', 'Home Team', 'Home Score', 'Away Team', 'Away Score', 'Date Keep']
    r = requests.get('%s&teamTabs=results' % v)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')

    h_scores = [int(i.text) for i in soup.select('.score a em:first-child')]
    a_scores = [int(i.text) for i in soup.select('.score a em + em')]

    limit = len(a_scores)
    comps = [i.text for i in soup.select('.tournament a', limit=limit)]
    dates = [i.text for i in soup.select('.dateTime .hide', limit=limit)]
    h_teams = [i.text for i in soup.select('.homeTeam a', limit=limit)]
    a_teams = [i.text for i in soup.select('.awayTeam a', limit=limit)]

    df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(comps, h_teams, h_scores, a_teams, a_scores, dates)),
                      columns=headers)

    df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\harsh\Desktop\MY DREAM\Soccer DB\%s.csv' % k, sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig', index=False)
```

Am I supposed to add to the `teams_dict={}` ? And what format?

This community has been so awesome so far! Love and gratitude!

Comment: `Such that the output remains the same i.e. Teams data getting downloaded in their respective csv files. How can I go along with it?` - the files are already names like that. `for k, v in teams_dict.items():` - k is the name, v is the link. You can refactor rename those variables for better code readability and understanding (I'd suggest at least renaming k into team_name). Then `...\%s.csv' % k` puts the team name in the file name.

Comment: This code downloads only for the Premier league. I would like to download many such leagues as well. How do I go alongwith that?

Comment: You could write an analogical code for other leagues - the site's format may be different, so I'm not sure about directly reusing it. First learn what each part of this code does and why. Then it would be easier to make something similar.

Comment: @h4z3 what would it be for other leagues? Can you please help? Many thanks.

Comment: And how would I know? I don't know those websites, so how would I know how the data is structured there? Also, SO is for concrete problems, not "write the code for me".

Comment: True. Yes, I am not asking to write the code for me. I dont want to do that. However, can you please identify how `https://www.soccerbase.com/teams/team.sd?team_id=965&comp_id=66&teamTabs=results` is different from what the code is downloading.